# Index of the max element of a list?

Tags: python, list, max

So I need to write and test a function that returns the index of the largest element in the list (or, if several elements have he largest value, the index of the first one of them) and I'm not allowed to use the max function.

```
def largestElementIndex(lst):
    x=0
    maxNum=0
    while x+1 < len(lst):
        if lst[x] > maxNum:
            maxNum=x
        x+=1
    return maxNum

print "Program Output"
indexOfMax = largestElementIndex([1, 4, 3, 3, 2])
print 'Index Of Max Value is',indexOfMax
```

Comment: Does this code not work?

Answer (score 5):

You need to store the largest number as well as the index:

```
def largestElementIndex(lst):
    x=0
    maxNum=0
    maxIndex=0

    while x < len(lst):
        if lst[x] > maxNum:
            maxIndex=x
            maxNum=lst[x]
        x+=1
    return maxIndex
```

I'd also use a `for` loop:

```
def largestElementIndex(lst):
    max_index = 0
    max_value = lst[0]

    for index, value in enumerate(lst)
        if value > max_value:
            max_index = index
            max_value = value

    return max_index
```

To do this with `max`, you use `enumerate` the same way:

```
max_index = max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda pair: pair[1])[0]
```

Comment: The first version should have `while x < len(lst):`. Currently you won't get the correct result when the highest value is the last element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this simple approach if you don't want to use max function:

```
res = lst.index(sorted(lst)[-1])
```

cheers!